# How to bind v-model with select if i have foreach in foreach?

Tags: vue.js

When i `alert(this.property_credentials.district)` in vue.js i get empty

```
<select v-model="property_credentials.district" name="district" class="country selectpicker" id="selectCountry" data-size="10" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="0">--Please select your district</option>
        @foreach($districts as $district)
            <optgroup label="{{$district->district}}">
                @foreach($district->regions as $region)
                   <option value={{ $region}} {{ (old("district") ==  $region? 'selected':'') }}>{{ $region}}</option>
                      @endforeach
 </optgroup>
@endforeach
```

How can i pass this value `$region` to vue.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of looping is wrong, there is no `@foreach` in vuejs, you will have to use [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for) to loop in the template. It should be something like:

```
<select v-model="property_credentials.district" name="district" class="country selectpicker" id="selectCountry" data-size="10" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="0">--Please select your district</option>
        <div v-for="district in $districts">
            <optgroup label="{{district->district}}">
                <div v-for="region in district.regions">
                   <option value={{region}} {{ (old("district") ==  region? 'selected':'') }}>{{ $region}}</option>
                 </div>
           </optgroup>
        </div>
```

Comment: im getting value from controller and i just want to bind that what ever user choose??

Comment: so i can not use values from laravel controller and bind them with v-model ?

Comment: No, With v-model, you will have to use vue data, which will be reactive.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different syntax together, you are using blade code with VueJs. data binding will be wrong.

What you need to do is to bind the value from laravel to a variable that vuejs can consume, something like this

`Laravel blade`

```
<script>
// this must be a json value
window.districts = {{$districts}}     
</script>
```

In your VueJS code you need to bind this value to your data array, then you can use it